# Exemplos com comparação com tipos

Tags: php, php-7.1

Olá, estou querendo entender uma parte da documentação PHP e não estou conseguindo. Quero entender a parte que fala de comparação com vários tipos.

Veja mais nesse link: https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.operators.comparison.php na parte **comparação com vários tipos**, eu não entendo os exemplos, poderiam dar exemplos com código escrito em php de como que é feito aquilo que está escrito na documentação (se baseando na documentação)?

Fiz assim no IDEONE do primeiro exemplo e o resultado não foi como está escrito na documentação.

**Exemplo:**

```
<?php
$palavra = NULL;
$palavra2 = "Pão";

if($r = $palavra == $palavra2) {
var_dump($r);
} else {
var_dump($r);
}

?>
```

Não foi o resultado que a documentação diz, poderiam da exemplos de alguns daqueles modelos para eu entender.

Queria entender essas documentações do PHP. Uso o PHP 7 e estou iniciando no mundo PHP, mais já conheço PHP por um bom tempo, mas agora estou começando a programar nele.

Comment: Dizer não entendi é muito complicado, tente ser mais específico. Do jeito que está cada um vai dar uma resposta diferente e pode ser nenhuma útil porque ninguém sabe qual é sua dúvida. No momento há uma descrição da sua situação, não uma dúvida, precisamos de dúvidas para ajudar.

Comment: Quero exemplo reais do que é discutido na seção comparação com vários tipos, eu não entendi como fazer aquilo no código.

Comment: Qual foi o resultado e qual era o resultado esperado?

Comment: o resultado foi FALSE, o resultado esperado é o que diz na documentação do PHP: "Converte NULL para "", numérico ou comparação léxica" e eu não entendi isso e o resultado nem foi o que diz a documentação